# how to use for loop answer in arrays in the same code?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

How can I convert k into an array?

```
z=str.length(); 
for(c='A';c<='z';c++) 
{
    k=0;
    for(y=0;y<z;y++)
    {
        ch=str.charAt(y);
        if(ch==c)
        {
            k++;
        }
    }
    if(k>0)
    {
        System.out.println(c + " occured " + k);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? `for(y=0;y0)` is **definitely** not correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get an array of frequency counts of the characters in a string, here's how:

```
    String str = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
    int[] k = new int['z' - 'A' + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'z')
            k[str.charAt(i) - 'A']++;
    }
    for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'z'; ++c) {
        System.out.println(c + " occurred " + k[c - 'A'] + " times");
    }
```